# When should I use the term 'paperworks'?

Tags: grammar

I keep seeing words like these. 
Another example is:

> Stuffs

Is this valid? People use it like this...

> There are so many things I have to sell. I have books, bags, clothes and other stuffs.

Comment: What are paperworks? I don't know the term.

Comment: No.  Stuff is plural without the s.  Same thing with Paperwork.  It's plural without the s as well.

Comment: *Paperwork* is a collective noun, I think. I only see *stuffs* (the noun, not the verb form) as part of the somewhat archaic *foodstuffs.*

Comment: @DoWhileNot That's what I thought! I don't understand why so many people use it. It sounds incorrect!

Comment: I most often hear it from people who speak English as a second language and they know the rules of English, but not the exceptions to the rules when they show up.  English isn't like a lot of languages that were born and raised in one single place - it's a big mash up of many different languages, so it has some basic rules that are pretty easy to understand and then a huge mass of exceptions to those rules that you can only learn with experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither the term *paperworks* or *stuffs* would be appropriate for academic writing (unless it's discussing this particular phenomenon of the vernacular).

*Paperwork* and *stuff* (no 's' on either) would be the correct terms, as they're collective nouns and may be either singular or plural, depending on usage. I'd recommend not using the terms (especially *stuff*). Be more specific.